# My table headers are being displayed but no data is being fetched from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, join

This here is my join controller. There is no error but the problem is that the data is not being shown in the table. The headers from blade.php file are being shown but the data is not being fetched or shown in the table.

My Join Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
class JoinController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function report()
    {
        $data = DB::table('pmedicalreadings')
        ->join('medrecords','medrecords.id','=','pmedicalreadings.id')
        ->join('payments','payments.id','=','pmedicalreadings.id')
        ->select('pmedicalreadings.bp','pmedicalreadings.temp','pmedicalreadings.ecg','medrecords.prerecord','payments.ptype','payments.tpayment','payments.rpayment')
        ->get();
        return view('report',compact('data'));
    }
}
```

My Routes from web.php:

```
Route::post('/report','JoinController@report');
Route::get('/report', function () {
    return view('/report');
});
```

My report.blade.php file:

```
<center><h1>Patient Report</h1></center>
<form >
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr  class="bg-danger text-light">
            <th>Patient Blood Pressure Reading</th>
            <th>Patient Temperature Reading</th>
            <th>Patient ECG Reading</th>
            <th>Patient Medical Record</th>
            <th>Payment Type</th>
            <th>Total Payment</th>
            <th>Remaining Payment</th>
        </tr>
        @if(isset($data))
            @foreach($data as $row)
                <tr  class="bg-secondary text-light">
                    <td>{{$row->bp}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->temp}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->ecg}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->prerecord}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->ptype}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->tpayment}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row->rpayment}}</td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    </table>
</form>
```

Here is the output I'm getting,

[image]

Comment: Seems like no data is being fetched. Your joins seem odd, are `pmedicalreadings.id`, `payments.id` and `medrecords.id` all really one-to-one relationships?

Comment: @El_Vanja Sir, I did not make any relationships. I was taking help from a youtube video I just kept following the steps. Before fetching data in the table. The controller was showing the data correctly but it won't fetch on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your web routes. Your get request doesnt return any data. It just returns the blade. You return the data in the post request. When you access the url your are making a get request

Comment: Sir, I removed the get route and now I have this error, The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Comment: Yes. Because you have no route declared for the get, anymore. Your post route does what a get request should do. Use post only when you need to send some user inputs to your backend. Use get to retrieve information. Instead of Route::post('/report','JoinController@report');    have Route::get('/report','JoinController@report');

Comment: Thankyou so much its retrieving data now I changed the post to get route. Im still learning and a newbie.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as useful.